# How to get Google Apps Launcher, Google Now, and Notifications

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I have Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 on Ubuntu 14.04 and have enabled the Chrome flag 'Enable the App Launcher. Linux'.

How do I get the new features - Google Apps Launcher, Google Now and Google Notifications - to appear?

Answer (score 11):

To get the Google App Launcher on your Ubuntu Unity task bar:

1. Install the [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) browser
2. Launch *Google Chrome* and enter the address `chrome://flags/#enable-app-list`
3. Click *enable* for the setting named **Enable the App Launcher.** Linux
4. Open the *Unity Launcher* and type *Chrome App* to find the *Chrome App Launcher* in your Applications list
5. Launch the *Chrome App Launcher* and you should see the icon appear in the Unity Launcher sidebar
6. Right-click on the *Chrome App Launcher* in the *Unity Launcher* sidebar and select *Lock to Launcher*
7. Now hold a left-click and then drag the *Chrome App Launcher* icon up to the top of the *Unity Launcher* sidebar so it is just below the *Unity Launcher* icon at top-right

You should now have a *Google App Launcher* in your *Unity Launcher* sidebar that provides a handy shortcut to your most used Google applications. You should also ensure that the *Google Chrome* browser is set to run in the background so that you continue to get notifications from Hangouts and other applications. To do that, just

1. launch the *Google Chrome* browser,
2. Find the [image: Google Chrome] icon in the notifications area (top-right of the desktop)
3. Left-click on the [image: Google Chrome] icon and check the option to *Let Google Chrome run in the background*

*Google Chrome* notifications settings can be controlled from the *Google Chrome* browser settings. Instructions for these are outlined on this *[Advanced Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/topic/3434353)* topic titled *[Turn notifications on or off](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216)*

Comment: Chris, couldn't find the setting `Enable the App Launcher. Linux`. I tried to search with "App Launcher.." etc with no luck. Removed?

Answer (score 4):

To enable the App Launcher:

- enabled the Chrome flag 'Enable the App Launcher. Linux'
- restart Chrome
- install one app from Chrome Store from the category "for your desktop"
- Done.

Google Now and Google Notifications ... still trying ... suggestions ???

Answer (score 3):

Sorry gents,
Launcher is retiring now. For me it's already disappeared in Apps Store.
[Check this link](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/03/retiring-chrome-app-launcher.html)

Comment: Side note from the link: "Chrome apps can still be accessed by clicking the apps shortcut in the bookmarks bar or typing chrome://apps in the omnibox."

Answer (score 1):

You can install WebCatalog from software center or download it from [here](https://webcatalog.io/) or:

```
sudo apt install webcatalog
```

Then, start WebCatalog

In the search bar type whatever you want to install.

Like:

Linkedin, telegram web, whatsupp, Allo, Microsoft office and etc.

After installing, you can just start it by searching(no need to search it from webcatalog anymore).